# Basis and kernel of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S : \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ defined as $S(x) = (\frac{\langle u,x\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle})u$ with $u := [u_1,u_2,u_3]$ a vector(not the zero vector) in $\mathbb{R^3}$ . What would be the standard basis for S and what would be the dim of the kernel (i assume that $u_3 \neq 0 $.)

Comment: What are your attempts? This site is not for solving homework problems for you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998211/questions-about-linear-transformation

Comment: Why does this question get an upvote? It shows absolutely no effort whatsoever and is basically a duplicate of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998211/265466) asked less then a day ago.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Since $S$ is projection onto $u$, the kernel is everything orthogonal to $u$.  So $v\in\operatorname{ker} S\iff v\cdot u=0$.  So the kernel is $2$ dimensional:   choose anything for $v_1$ and $v_2$, then $v_3=\frac{-u_1v_1-u_2v_2}{u_3}$.

I presume you mean the matrix rel the standard basis $\beta=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.  Simply apply $S$ to each $e_i$ and write the result in terms of $\beta$ to get the $i$th column of the matrix.   For the first column,  I get $\frac1{u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2}\cdot (u_1^2,u_1u_2,u_1u_3)$.  I leave the other two to you.

If, on the other hand, you wanted a basis for the image of $S$, you could use $\{u\}$.

Comment: Thank you ! So the standard basis of S is  $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ so the dimension of S is 3 ?

Comment: The rank of $S$ is $1$.  The nullity,  the dimension of the kernel,  is $2$.